# 'mydata$column <- NULL' not working in function

Tags: r

This is the function:

```
remove_column <- function(column_vector) {
  for (column in column_vector) {
    if (grepl('.y$', column)) {
      mydata$column <- NULL
    }
  } 
}
```

What I think it'd doing: I'm passing a vector of my column names to the function, it's looping through list of names and asking whether the last characters of each column name are ".y". If that is the case, the function eliminates the column.

I've tried putting prints here and there to see my vector and to see whether the conditional evaluates to TRUE or FALSE, and everything seems to be working fine, but for some reason, it doesn't get rid of the column.

The following function returns my column vector:

```
duplicate_names <- function(col_names) {
  duplicates <- c()
  for (name in col_names) {
    # split by period i.e. colname.x would be [colname, x]
    if (lengths(strsplit(name, '\\.')) > 1) {
      duplicates <- c(duplicates, name)
    }
  }
  return(duplicates)
}
```

I usually call it like this:

```
duplicate_names(names(mydata))
```

This is what the vector of columns looks like:

```
c('v1.x', 'v2.y')
```

When I print the function it returns the following:

```
[1] "v1.x" "v2.y"
```

As requested by a user, the dput(droplevels(horsedata[1:5, 1:5])) (data that I am using for this):

```
dput(droplevels(horsedata[1:5, 1:5]))
structure(list(ÿþhorse_name = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("IM PRETTY FAMES", 
"JESS ROYAL BUCKS", "KISS ME IM SUGAR", "LOLAMO", "RUN MADISON RUN"
), class = "factor"), owner_name = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
4L), .Label = c("Christine Tavares", "Heste Sport, Inc.", "Picov Cattle Co.", 
"Procter, Wayne and Carol", "Ruth F. Barbour"), class = "factor"), 
    program = structure(1:5, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
    ), class = "factor"), pp = 1:5, todays_cls = c(61L, 61L, 
    61L, 61L, 61L)), .Names = c("ÿþhorse_name", "owner_name", 
"program", "pp", "todays_cls"), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Instead of the for loop function, I can get the duplicates using `nm1 <- sub('\\..$', '', names(merged_data));
dup_names <- nm1[duplicated(nm1)|duplicated(nm1, fromLast=TRUE)]` but one problem is `[1] "\U3e66663c\U3e65663cstat_breed" "\U3e66663c\U3e65663cstat_breed"`

Comment: Actually, it should be `dup_names <- names(merged_data)[duplicated(nm1)|duplicated(nm1, fromLast=TRUE)]`. Then I get `dup_names
#[1] "\xff\xfestat_breed.x" "\xff\xfestat_breed.y"`.  Somehow, this is not working with the function.

Comment: Yes! I don't understand either! The function makes complete sense

Comment: Just add `perl=TRUE` in the `grepl`.  It works for me now.  Updated the remove_column function.  Also, instead of the loop `duplicate_names` function, you can use the vectorized one.

Comment: `'\xff\xfestat_breed.y' %in% colnames(remove_column(merged_data, dup_names)) #
[1] FALSE`

Comment: If this works, we can clean up the comments

Comment: still doesn't work :( this is my new script with the corrected functions: https://gist.github.com/DevKiddo/5b8244843c4aeb7ca5c4 Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I guess you are not assigning the result to a new object i.e. `merged_data1 <- remove_column(merged_data,duplicates_list); names(merged_data1)`  and check the `ncol` i.e. `ncol(merged_data)
#[1] 93;
 ncol(merged_data1)
#[1] 88`

Comment: Just to make it clear `duplicates_list
# [1] "\xff\xfestat_breed.x" "\xff\xfestat_breed.y" "tran_disp.x"         
 #[4] "train_key.x"          "t_type.x"             "trainer_Id.x"        
 #[7] "tran_disp.y"          "train_key.y"          "t_type.y"            
#[10] "trainer_Id.y" ;     intersect(duplicates_list, colnames(merged_data1))
#[1] "\xff\xfestat_breed.x" "tran_disp.x"          "train_key.x"         
#[4] "t_type.x"             "trainer_Id.x" `

Comment: Hi @akrun, remember that function you gave me to detect the duplicate names? (`dup_names` a little above this comment). Would you mind telling me how I could modify it in order to return duplicates without being case sensitive?

Comment: You can change `nm1` to lower or upper case and then do the `duplicated` i.e. `nm2 <- toupper(nm1); names(merged_data)[duplicated(nm2)|duplicated(nm2, fromLast=TRUE)]`

Comment: ah! good work around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need a loop to subset the columns.

```
mydata[!grepl('\\.y$', column_list)]
```

If there are other columns not in the `column_list` and we want to keep them (assuming that the 'column_list' is ordered)

```
mydata[setdiff(1:ncol(mydata), grep('\\.y$', column_list))]
```

---

We can modify your function by

1. changing `.y$` to `\\.y$` as `.` means any character and not just the `dot`
2. Instead of `$`, we use `[` to subset the dataset
3. Return the dataset after the assignment

---

```
remove_column <- function(dat, column_vec) {
 for (column in column_vec) {
  if (grepl('\\.y$', column, perl=TRUE)) {
   dat[column] <- NULL
       }
    }
  dat
}

remove_column(mydata, column_list)
#   v1.x v2.x v3
#1     6    1  9
#2     4   11  7
#3    14   15  5
#4    10    2  4
#5    13    4  0
#6    19   14  1
#7     5    1  8
#8    16   12  7
#9    16   13  5
#10    5    0  7
```

#### data

```
mydata <- structure(list(v1.x = c(6L, 4L, 14L, 10L, 13L, 19L, 5L, 16L, 
16L, 5L), v1.y = c(12L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 6L, 18L, 4L, 0L, 10L, 2L
), v2.x = c(1L, 11L, 15L, 2L, 4L, 14L, 1L, 12L, 13L, 0L), v2.y = c(6L, 
5L, 7L, 3L, 19L, 4L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 20L), v3 = c(9L, 7L, 5L, 
4L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 7L, 5L, 7L)), .Names = c("v1.x", "v1.y", "v2.x", 
"v2.y", "v3"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

column_list <- c('v1.x', 'v1.y', 'v2.x', 'v2.y')
```

Comment: @jgozal You can convert this to a function (just updated the post).  `this is not working for me` doesn't give much info though.

Comment: I wish I could give you more info but I am not getting any console errors. I think I just discovered the root of my problem. The list that I was passing in my first function is not a list, it's type is a character. I'll try to fix that first

Comment: @jgozal It's not clear without a reproducible example. i.e just like I showed you can update your post with a small example using `?dput` ie. `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))`

Comment: @jgozal Do you have other columns in the dataset that are  not in the column_list?

Comment: yes I do have other columns. I apologize - I will update the post with a reproducible example and add in the function that returns the list of column names that I am dealing with.